# Can we get a single extentReport and single cucumber json report for the first run and failed test rerun using Selenium, cucumber and extentReport?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, extentreports, retry-logic

When we use the
@CucumberOptionsplugin = { "rerun:failedTest/failedTestList.txt" }
and rerun the failed test, it override the existing extentReport. We can get the multiple cucumber json for first run and rerun of failed test.
Is there any solution, we can get the combined extentReport for first and failed rerun?
Also, can we get the combined json report?

First run extentReport is override by the rerun of failed test.